# How do I display a message box on exit if changes have been made?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If a user has made changes to the image in the picture box such as using the Rotate R, Rotate L buttons, and then the user clicks on the exit button I want it to display a message box saying "Would you like to save changes to the following items?" I can't seem to do it, this is all I've got.

Comment: What is `RotRButton_Click`? Is that a function? What does it do?

Comment: Yeah RotRButton_Click is a function it Rotates the image 90 degrees to the right

Comment: You may want to consider using the FormClosing event for this.  This will all close events (e.g. user clicks on X close button, right clicks on the task bar, etc..).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set a flag to determine if the button was clicked. And then check that flag in the `Exit_Click`:

```
private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_rotrButtonClicked &&
        MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save this file?",
            "Media Player",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // save the changes
    }
}
```

You can declare the flag as a `private` field on the form:

```
private bool _rotrButtonClicked;
```

and then in the `RotRButton_Click` set it:

```
_rotrButtonClicked = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, a red line underlines the messagebox for some reason in the MessageBox("Would you like to save this file?") why is this?

Comment: This is what it says Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: It should be MessageBox.Show :)

Comment: now it is correct.. It should be `MessageBox.Show(...)` rather than `MessageBox(...).Show()`!

Comment: @neoistheone Thanks guys but the MessageBox( still has a red underline:/

Comment: @neoistheone instead of having to repeat the code for each button is a more efficient way of doing it so that the message box appears when every button is clicked rather than just the rotateRbutton

Comment: @rvngkaz, if you have more than one button that can "cause a change" then just set that flag to `true` in every button click. That would ensure that it will get shown on exit, regardless of what button was clicked that caused the change. You could even change the flag to `_pendingChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

You should encapsulate the logic into a class that can track the change status for you.  E.G.

```
public class ImageMutator
{
    private bool HasChanged { get; set; }   
    private PictureBox myPictureBox {get;set}
    public ImageMutator(PictureBox pictureBox)//Most abstract type that has functionality
    {
       myPictureBox = pictureBox;
    }
    public void RotateRight()
    {
        HasChanged = true;
        //manipulate myPictureBox
    }

    public void RotateLeft()
    {
        HasChanged = true;
        //manipulate myPictureBox
    }

    //other methods

    public void ConfirmChange()
    {
        if (HasChanged)
        {
            var save = (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save this file?", "Media Player", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes);
            if (save)
            {
                //Save
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add this class as a member of the form and confirm on exit:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ImageMutator mutator ;/private member "has-a" relationship

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mutator = new ImageMutator(pictureBox);//whatever image type is
    }

    private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mutator.ConfirmChange();//Only saves if mutation occurred         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to track changes when the user clicks on the Rotate buttons. The in the exit button you just check the value of the variable to know whether there has been changes or not:

```
private bool hasChanges = false;

private void RotRButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    hasChanges = true;
}

private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hasChanges)
    {
        if (MessageBox("Would you like to save this file?", "Media Player", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
           //Do something
        }

    }
}
```